# Demandware: How to get promotion using shipping method ID

Tags: demandware

I been searching this through reading the documentation how to get the promotion attached to the shipping method which I am planning to use the shipping method ID as identifier.

Looks like this code :

```
dw.order.ShippingLineItem.getShippingPriceAdjustments()
```

But I don't know how can I get the promotion using the shipping method ID.

Anyone?

Answer (score 5):

```
PromotionMgr.getActiveCustomerPromotions().getShippingPromotions(shippingMethod : ShippingMethod)
```

Explanation:

- `getActiveCustomerPromotions()` get all activated promotions for current user (storefront user). You can get global promotions by `getActivePromotions()`
- `getShippingPromotions()` get promotions will be activated for specific shipping method
- Get shipping method via `ShippingMgr` class.